# Question regarding Jensen Inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, solution-verification, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

Following is the picture of the question regarding the application of Jensen Inequality.

[image: question regarding application of the Jensen Inequality from the book challenge and thrill of Pre college mathematics]

Following is the picture my approach to proove the inequality.

[image: my approach...sorry or the bad handwriting !]

Can anyone please check if my proof
is acceptable...i feel that this is an elegant proof.

If there is any error, a detailed explanation would be helpful and appreciated.

Thank you

Also, appologies for the bad handwriting

Comment: This is difficult to read. Please take the time to write your proof as text. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step $$\frac{n}{1-\frac{(a_1+...+a_n)^2}{n^2}}\geq\frac{n}{1-\frac{a_1^2+...+a_n^2}{n}}$$ is wrong: it should be 
$$\frac{n}{1-\frac{(a_1+...+a_n)^2}{n^2}}\leq\frac{n}{1-\frac{a_1^2+...+a_n^2}{n}},$$ which does not help.

My solution.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{1-a_i^2}-\frac{na}{1-a^2}=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{a_i}{1-a_i^2}-\frac{a}{1-a^2}\right)=\frac{1}{1-a^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(a_i-a)(aa_i+1)}{1-a_i^2}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{1-a^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{(a_i-a)(aa_i+1)}{1-a_i^2}-\frac{(a_i^2-a^2)(a^2+1)}{2a(1-a^2)}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2a(1-a^2)^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(a_i-a)^2(a_i^2+(2a^3+a^2+2a)a_i+3a^2-1)}{1-a_i^2}\geq0.$$

Comment: Oh ! I committed a silly mistake....i got your solution...thankyou

Comment: Could you please please suggest me that how can i develope such intuition to prove Olympiad inequalities

Comment: @user 493905 It's impossible to say in one post. But the first thing it's to solve very many problems.

Comment: Well i am familiar with that...but what if I am unable to bring that insight or the intuition required to solve those problems....like in the above question your and my approaches are to the same problem are contrasting...you were able to find which step will lead you to the answer req. while i was not.

Comment: And how much in average time should I devote to one problem

Comment: @user 493905 The time is not relevant (maybe in the contest only). Number of problems, which you can solve (or can understand the solution) in one day and every day, it's relevant. It should be at least five problems by the IMO's level.

Comment: I see...i have been unjustifiably blocked by the community to ask further questions on inequalities....could you please suggest me any other forum or community where questions concerning mathematics are answered like here....do you clear doubts via email or can you please suggest sites which offer tutors or mentors  who teach Olympiad level mathematics... I am a beginner and I need a guidance.... please help

Comment: @user 493905 There is the following forum: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6_inequalities  I think, it's impossible that you have been  blocked by the community to ask further questions on inequalities. If so, send to the administration of the site. I think he will help you.

Comment: They say that they are no longer accepting questions from my account

Comment: Which book would you refer me as the best one for mastering Olympiad inequalities?

Comment: @user 493905 Vasile Citroaje "Mathematical Inequalities", Ploiesti University, 2015-2018, (5 volumes).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and recommendations

Comment: Could you please state the generalized Chebishev inequality for the sequence of real 
numbers $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$, $b_1, b_2,..., b_n$, and $m_1, m_2,..., m_n$ where $a_1 < a_2 <...,< a_n$, $b_1 > b_2 >...,> b_n$ and $m_1 + m_2 + ... + m_n = 1$ ?

Comment: Unable to find online... I guess it's not present

Comment: I don't know about this inequality.

Comment: Can you please tell me that how can one find the values of variables in an inequality for which an equality will occur.

Is there any meathod to determine the condition that when will an equality take place ?

Comment: @user 493905 In the general we have no some method. Sometimes it's enough to check an equality case of all variables, sometimes it's enough to check an equality case of some number of variables, sometimes we need to check, what happens, when one of variables is equal to zero, sometimes it's just an unnecessary work, which only harms to the inequality proof.

Comment: Actually I am working with inequalities which require the  application of uvw meathod...to be accurate the symmetric transformation of cyclic inequalities from the book "diamonds in mathematical inequalities"....there i need to figure out the condition for equality

Comment: Can you please refer any book other than what i mentioned above which can give me a good grip on UVW-Meathod ?

Comment: @user 493905 There is my paper about this method. But it's in Russian. see also here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Comment: Unfortunately I can't understand russian.....are you a member of AoPS community ?......i am there as 'Kgxtixigct'...if possible can you please answer my problems on inequalities which I have posted there regarding the application of uvw meathod....they have not got a good response.

Comment: In evening. OK?

Comment: Ok fine...thank you

Comment: @If you meant the following https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2145979 so post it on this forum.

Comment: I have been blocked from asking questions here....they say that i I have reached my question limit

Comment: Can you please try to provide a solution over there or create a question over here and answer it yourself ?

Comment: It would be of great help